# How to pass stateSave in Shiny when I have ui.R and Server.R file separate?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server

I want to pass saveState argument in my shiny server.

I found following code from https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/76

```
DTApp = function(data, ..., options = list()) {
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
     verbatimTextOutput('foo'),
     DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
     options$ajax = list(url = dataTableAjax(session, data))
     # create a widget using an Ajax URL created above
     widget = datatable(data, server = TRUE, ..., options = options)
     output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(widget)
     output$foo = renderPrint(str(input$tbl_state))
  }
 )
}

DTApp(iris, options = list(stateSave = TRUE))
```

As we can see here, They has pass stateSave in DTApp. However, I am building ui and server seperate. Rstudio is building app for me.

I have no idea, where to pass stateSave argument. I believe it should go into server, however, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`stateSave` is just an option for `datatable`. So change the following line

```
 widget = datatable(data, server = TRUE, ..., options = options)
```

to

```
 widget = datatable(data, server = TRUE, ..., options = list(stateSave = TRUE))
```

Comment: It didn't work, I am reading table using reactiveFileReader with 60000. Since, data table is large, we can't load every time,therefore, I have to use reactiveFileReader. I don't know if it is related or not